# Where is the content of a Java piped stream 'stored'?

Tags: java, memory, stream, profiler

I am running my application under a profiler. The 'class' that has the most memory consumption is the `char[]` which is about 10 kB in my application.

I then created an `InputStream` (`PipedInputStream` to be exact) which holds a byte array data of 300 MB.

Then I took a look at my profiler, and I don't see any significant change ( don't see anywhere that something eats up 300 MB).

The question is, if that 300 MB of byte array is not in memory, where is Java keeping it?

**[Update]**
Additional info on how I got the 300 MB to my `PipedInputStream`:

I am developing a web app that has a file upload mechanism.
And in one of the processes in my file upload, I create an input stream (`PipedInputStream`). Basically,

1. I read the multipartfile's input stream (a few KB of byte[] at a time),
2. Created a `PipedOutputStream`
3. Created a `PipedInputStream` (passing the recently created output stream to the constructor)
4. Wrote the multipart's input stream to my `PipedOutputStream` (running on a separated thread; which flushes and closes that output stream before exiting the thread). *At this point, I now have a copy of the multipart's bytes in my own input stream*
5. Then (accidentally) stored that input stream in my http session (discussion/debate on whether that is a good idea would be on a different question)

So the question then again is, where is Java keeping my `InputStream`'s content (I don't see it anywhere in my profiler)?

**[Update#2]**

I have a `FileOutputStream` which reads from the `PipedInputStream` and writes to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PipedInputStream` just makes data available when it's written by the output stream that it's connected to. So long as you keep reading from your input stream as fast as it receives data from the output stream, there won't be much data to buffer.

If that doesn't help, you'll need to give more information about what you're doing with the piped input stream - what output stream is it connected to, and what's reading from it?

**EDIT:** You still haven't said what's reading from your `PipedInputStream`. Something must be, as otherwise the `PipedOutputStream` would block - `PipedInputStream` only have a fairly small buffer (by default).

Comment: Additional information has been provided in the question. Thanks

Comment: sorry about that. just added update #2. ..And I'm now starting to understand what you're trying to say. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A [`PipedInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) does not store any data at all. Also, where do you get that 300 MB byte array from?

Comment: Additional information has been provided in the question. Thanks

Comment: A PipedInputStream *does* store data - it stores whatever has been written to the attached output stream, but not read from the input stream yet. However, it shouldn't buffer *much* data...

Comment: This answer is wrong. PipedInputStream has a 1k buffer by default. This size can be changed by overriding the class. When the buffer is full, waiting for a thread to read from the the stream, the connected PipedOutputStream will block on write operations. Otherwise, both threads are runnable.